# Filter List By User Group

Tags: filter, groups

I am running SharePoint Foundation on Windows 7.
I am trying to filter a list based upon the user group a person may belong to.  If the current user is member of the Division Managers group, then the division that they supervise will be retrieved.  I would like to filter the task order list by the Division field so the the division manager sees all task orders that have been assigne to their division.  If the current user is a member of the section manager group, then the section id that they supervise will be retrieved, and the task order list will be filtered by the section id field.  So they will see all task orders assigned to their section.
How do I do this and are there any filter web parts available to me in SharePoint Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the standard filter web parts are not part of Foundation.  With 2007 they were part of the enterprise features, and I believe they are with 2010 as well.

You do have the ability to develop a custom filter web part though that can provide much more complex functionality.

I'm really not sure how you would be able to do this out of the box anyway, even with the filter web parts in enterprise.  What it sounds like you want to do is a lookup for one or more groups that person is a member of and then filter the list.  That lookup would have to be custom code.

Answer (score 2):

One 3rd party tool (no connection) that will do this is Roxority FilterZen. They have a free 'lite' version.

http://roxority.com/sharepoint-zen/sharepoint-list-filtering-by-user-group-membership.html

Comment: Thank you Ryan.  I looked at the tool but it didn't seem to provide the functionality that I need.  What I am attempting to do is grab the Division ID from the User Information List IF the user is found in the Divsion Managers group.  If they are not there, but are in the Section Managers group, I need to get the Section ID from the User Information List so that I know which section they manage.  Then I can filter the task order list by this section ID.  Please let me know if I can achieve the same results with this tool.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sharepoint Designer to achieve this.

Check this http://sharepointcodes.com/filter-list-view-by-user-and-groups-in-sharepoint/